# PowerBI: Filtering a table based on a measure

Tags: date, filter, powerbi-desktop, measure

In powerbi, I have a visual table of sales. The data is aggregated every month and one of the columns is a date column which equals the first of the month of the month the sale was made in. So there are hundreds of entries of 01/02/2023, 01/03/2023 and so on. For the table I only want the previous month sales to be displayed. Currently I have a measure that equals the previous month. It calculates the max date, then the max date excluding that date and returns that value. I want a filter on the table so that the date column will only display values equal to that measure but can not seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated